Can we relate the dipole force on a two level atom to the AC stark shift it experiences?
Consider a two level atom, with ground state $|g\rangle$ and excited state $|e\rangle$. In the rotating frame, the dynamics of the two level atom interacting with radiation detuned by $\Delta$, and Rabi frequency $\Omega$ are given by the Hamiltonian:
$$\hat {H}=-\hbar \Delta |e\rangle \langle e|+{\frac {\hbar \Omega }{2}}(|e\rangle \langle g|+|g\rangle \langle e|)$$
The system now has different eigenvalues, $|\pm\rangle$ with eigenvalues
$${\displaystyle E_{\pm }={\frac {-\hbar \Delta }{2}}\pm {\frac {\hbar {\sqrt {\Omega ^{2}+\Delta ^{2}}}}{2}}}.$$
My question is, is the dipole force related to the fact that the energy of the system now depends on $\Omega$ and $\Delta$ and if this is the case, why is the force towards large $\Omega$ for negative $\Delta$ (red detuned) and towards small $\Omega$ for positive $\Delta$ (blue detuned). I want to think about this entirely in terms of the eigenstates of the quantum system.

It might be helpful if you can please include the actual expression for computing the dipole force you are referencing.  Thank you.
